# Getting error while adding plugin in app.module.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, camera, ionic-native

Whenever I am trying to add PhotoLibrary plugin in ionic, I am not able to add it in app.module.ts . I am getting the following error

```
Type 'PhotoLibraryOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'PhotoLibraryOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactory [2322]
(alias) const PhotoLibrary: PhotoLibraryOriginal
import PhotoLibrary
```

Please check the below image for full error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import from `/ngx` for all latest ionic native plugins used with `ionic-angular` apps...

> ```
> import { PhotoLibrary } from '@ionic-native/photo-library/ngx';
> ```

Else fallback to version 4.* of plugins

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day.